# 'imgAreaSelect' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I found some example but that one is not a angular [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/PdYB7/5/) and I  tried to created my `angular 6` project for the some image area selector but its not working correctly,i faced this error

> .component.ts(64,16): error TS2339: Property 'imgAreaSelect' does not
>   exist on type '"#bee"'.

anyone know how to put this one in Angular 6

[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggtn2q)

Thanks in advance

**component.html**

```
<div id="bee">
<img src="/assets/sg-img/documents/test-2.jpg" width="100%;">
        <!--- documents-->
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

     {
      ('#bee').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true });
    };
  }
```

**.css**

```
/*image area*/


.imgareaselect-border1, .imgareaselect-border2,
.imgareaselect-border3, .imgareaselect-border4 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-handle {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-outer {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-selection {
}
```

Comment: What this supposed to do? ('#whatever') will give you a string. Maybe you wanted jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to include JQuery as project dependency.  This part is done here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggtn2q?file=src%2Findex.html

Later on you have to include required plugin as static asset and include it as sources. This cannot be done on stackblitz. Required pligin sources you can get here 
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/imgareaselect

Here is explained how to include jquery plugin https://medium.com/all-is-web/angular-5-using-jquery-plugins-5edf4e642969